# Como fazer uma Query ignorando os espaços laterais do conteúdo da Coluna?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Bom dia pessoal!

Utilizando a Query:

`@Repository
public interface SessaoRepository extends AbstractRepository<Sessao, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Sessao p WHERE p.dc_secao =:dc_secao")
    Sessao getDcSessao(@Param("dc_secao") String dc_secao);
}`

Eu tenho um retorno que é um número, o problema é que dentro da tabela `Sessao` o dado dentro de `dc_secao` pode estar nesses dois casos:

```
     dc_secao           | cod_secao
  SECAO DO FUEGO          123810230
  /t/tSECAO DE GELO\t\t   3123131313
```

Ou seja, caso eu procure `SECAO DE GELO` não vou retornar nada, existe alguma `Query` em que eu consiga ignorar esses espaços(representados pelo `\t`) para trazer os resultados independente dos espaços laterais?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matheus,

Você pode utilizar a função `trim` no campo que deseja filtrar dentro do seu where, algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessao p WHERE trim(p.dc_secao) = 'SECAO DE GELO';
```

Caso você possua tabulações, o `trim` pode não funciona, para isso existe o `btrim`, que você pode enviar um char que será substituído, então você envia o char referente a tabulação, em Postgres pode-se utilizar o `chr(9)`:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessao p WHERE btrim(p.dc_secao, chr(9)) = 'SECAO DE GELO';
```

É possível misturar as funções, chamar uma função com o retorno de outra:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessao p WHERE trim(btrim(p.dc_secao, chr(9))) = 'SECAO DE GELO';
```

Também é possível utilizar o operador `like` do SQL, onde o % representa um *coringa*, com isso você consegue ignorar o começo e o final do termo pesquisado, essa forma pode representar um risco para a pesquisa, visto que ele procura um contido, você pode retornar algum dado indevido, mas fica aí a ideia:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessao p WHERE p.dc_secao like '%SECAO DE GELO%';
```

Veja online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fdd5/3

> Referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html

Comment: vou testar, valeu

Comment: O trim não está funcionando da forma esperada, e o like é problemático por que retorna mais de um resultado de uma Query que deveria ser única.
Parece que o postgres não retira \t com trim..

Comment: Matheus, talvez você não tenha espaços ou somente espaços, caso seja uma tabulação, o trim pode não funcionar, teste com o btrim, editei e coloquei um exemplo, se não funcionar, procure descobrir qual é exatamente esse char, pois parece não ser apenas um espaço.

Comment: A combinação de `trim` e `btrim` foi suficiente, valeu.